# Why is Id returning null and not returning the next Id from the database?

Tags: c#, .net, angular

Why is Id returning null and not returning the next Id from the database? I think the Id should be the next id that is available from the database. Instead it is just returning a null value. Below is my component. Whenever is console.log(this.vehicle.id) I get NaN and on the browser the value is null. I need some help figuring out what I am doing wrong.

```
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  makes: any;
  models: any[];
  features: any;
  vehicle: SaveVehicle = {
    id: 0,
    makeId: 0,
    modelId: 0,
    isRegistered: false,
    features: [],
    contact: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: ''
    }
  };
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private vehicleService: VehicleService, private toastrService: ToastrService) {
    route.params.subscribe(p => {
      this.vehicle.id = +p['id'];
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.vehicle.id.toFixed(1));
    const sources = [
      this.vehicleService.getMakes(),
      this.vehicleService.getFeatures(),
    ];
    if (this.vehicle.id) {
      sources.push(this.vehicleService.getVehicle(this.vehicle.id));
    }
    forkJoin(sources).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.makes = data[0];
      this.features = data[1];
      if (this.vehicle.id) {
        this.setVehicle(data[2]);
        this.populateModels();
      }
    }, err => {
      if (err.status == 404) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }
  private setVehicle(v: Vehicle) {
    this.vehicle.id = v.id;
    this.vehicle.makeId = v.make.id;
    this.vehicle.modelId = v.model.id;
    this.vehicle.isRegistered = v.isRegistered;
    this.vehicle.contact = v.contact;
    this.vehicle.features = _.pluck(v.features, 'id');
  }
  onMakeChange() {
    this.populateModels();
    delete this.vehicle.modelId;
  }
  private populateModels() {
    const selectedMake = this.makes.find((m: { id: number; }) => m.id == this.vehicle.makeId);
    this.models = selectedMake ? selectedMake.models : [];
  }
  onFeatureToggle(featureId: number, $event: { target: { checked: any; }; }) {
    if ($event.target.checked) {
      this.vehicle.features.push(featureId);
    } else {
      const index = this.vehicle.features.indexOf(featureId);
      this.vehicle.features.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  submit() {
    if (this.vehicle.id) {
      this.vehicleService.update(this.vehicle)
        .subscribe(x => {
          this.toastrService.success('The vehicle was sucessfully updated.', 'Success');
        });
    } else {
      this.vehicleService.create(this.vehicle)
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
  }
```

Here is the endpoint that I created for a new vehicle to be added to the database

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVehicle([FromBody] SaveVehicleResource vehicleResource)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var vehicle = mapper.Map<SaveVehicleResource, Vehicle>(vehicleResource);
        vehicle.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

        repository.Add(vehicle);
        await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

        vehicle = await repository.GetVehicle(vehicle.Id);

        var result = mapper.Map<Vehicle, VehicleResource>(vehicle);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Here is SaveVehicleresouce.cs

```
public class SaveVehicleResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ContactResource Contact { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> Features { get; set; }

    public SaveVehicleResource()
    {
        Features = new Collection<int>();
    }
}
```

Here are the interfaces that I am using. I made int nullable?

```
export interface Vehicle {
  id: number;
  model: KeyValuePair;
  make: KeyValuePair;
  isRegistered: boolean;
  features: KeyValuePair[];
  contact: Contact;
  lastUpdate: string;
}

export interface SaveVehicle {
  id?: number;
  modelId: number;
  makeId: number;
  isRegistered: boolean;
  features: number[];
  contact: Contact;
}
```

Comment: And where does your problem lie? Is it in the C# code or in the Angular code not understanding the response? You can easily check this by examining the request/response with the Chrome debugger and thereby eliminate half of your question.

Comment: I get a 400 error whenever /api/vehicles is being called because Id is null. This is the error message `{"$.id":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10."]}` So according to that error message I think the problem is the C# code?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that you're sending an id which isn't an integer. You should check the request body, and ideally add it to your question, along with the SaveVehicleResource class definition.

Comment: I believe this is the request body `{"id":null,"makeId":"1","isRegistered":false,"features":[1],"contact":{"name":"John Doe","email":"Johndoe@gmail.com","phone":"4051234567"},"modelId":"1"}` I need the id to be initialized to the next id the is available from the database.

Comment: Well, you're sending `null`, and you're clearly trying to receive `int32`. In C#, `int32` can't be `null`. You haven't edited your question to include `SaveVehicleResource`, but perhaps you need to change it to a nullable int (i.e. `int?`)?

Comment: I added more source code to my question. I did make int? and that didnt work on angular. Not sure how to do it on the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
route.params.subscribe(p => {
  this.vehicle.id = +p['id'];
});
```

into `ngOnInit()`, and put the logic already there inside the subscription.

If the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle event fires before the `route.params` observable has fired, then id won't yet be set.

Answer (score 0):

Update, all I had to do is change

```
route.params.subscribe(p => {
      this.vehicle.id = +p['id'];
    });
```

to

```
route.params.subscribe(p => {
      this.vehicle.id = +p['id'] || 0;
    });
```